# Overloading return value of subclassed int in Python

Tags: python, subclassing

I want to call a function when the value of a subclassed int is requested. As far as I understand any attribute of a class is indirectly requested through `__getattribute__`, but it seems that immutable values of built-in classes are accessed by some other means, as overloading it does not affect return behavior. An explanation of why this is and how the return value is different from other class attributes (as well as a reference to documentation) would be greatly appreciated.

As an example, what would I put in my subclass of int to have the interactive interpreter return the following?:

```
>>> class IntSub(int):
...   def before(self):
...     print "value requested"
...   def after(self):
...     print "value returned"
... 
>>> intsub1 = IntSub(42)
>>> intsub2 = intsub1
value requested
value returned
>>>
```

**EDIT:**

I have found a couple of ways of getting halfway to the solution I seek, although not without calling a method that return the object.

1: By adding `get()` to `IntSub` and calling it when making an assignment the first of my conditions for a solution are satisfied:

```
...   def get(self):
...     self.before()
...     print "returning value"
...     return self
...
>>> subint1 = SubInt(42)
>>> subint2 = subint1.get()
value requested
returning value
>>>
```

2: Using a function decorator on `get()` it is possible to also satisfy the second of my conditions by jumping through a few hoops:

```
...   def decorate(decorating):
...     def decorated(self):
...       self.before()
...       result = decorating(self)
...       self.after()
...       return result
...     return decorated
...   @decorate
...   def get(self):
...     print "returning value"
...     return self
...     
>>> intsub1 = IntSub(42)
>>> intsub2 = intsub1.get()
value requested
returning value
value obtained
>>>
```

Still, the issue remains that these approaches requires adding `get()`, which is not satisfying. I wonder whether the solution I want could be achieved using a class decorator or a different meta-class. Advice and suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: The value of your `int` subclass is *the object itself*; there is no separate step being performed to retrieve the value.  Now, in your example of displaying the object in the REPL, the object is being called upon to generate a string representation of itself: you could modify that by overriding its `__repr__()` method.  But merely referencing the object, such as `x = intsub`, does not involve any methods of the object, and therefore cannot be overridden.

Comment: @jasonharper: Thank you for your input. I have updated my question to reflect that it is indeed the value referencing rather than the value representation accessed through `__repr__()` that I am interested in. I would greatly appreciate it if you would provide further explanation about how _the value is the object_ or alternatively point me to documentation that describes the functionality. So far Google has not been helpful in my search because I am unclear about what terminology is used to describe/discuss this particular subject.